# How to write Junit test case array matrix addition and multiplication?

Tags: java, matrix, junit, multiplication, addition

```
package testMatrix;

public class MatrixAdd {
    public int [][] addtionOfArray(int [][] numbers){
        int length = numbers.length;
        int output[][] = new int[length][length];
        for(int i=0; i< length; i++){
            for(int j=0; i< length; j++){
                output[i][j] = numbers[i][j] + numbers[i][j];
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

How to write Junit test for array matrix addition? and also Junit test for matrix multiplication

Comment: what kind of multiplication do you want to do? cross product or dot product?

For addition, the matrices need to be the same size, so it's easy to just add a second argument with the same size and use `output[i][j] = numbers1[i][j] + numbers2[i][j]`

Comment: I want Dot product array matix multiplication. How to write Junit test code for the above code and multiplication?

Comment: *i want to know how to write above code Junit test and dot product Junit test code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `test` source set you can use something similar

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class MatrixAddTest {

    private MatrixAdd testee = MatrixAdd();

    @Test
    public void testAdditionOfArray(){
        int[][] expected = new int[][]{new int[]{2, 0}, new int[]{0, 2}};
        int[][] actual = testee.addtionOfArray(new int[][]{new int[]{1, 0}, new int[]{0, 1}});
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

however, since MatrixAdd seems like a Utility class, you could also make the methods static, you don't really need a MatrixAdd instance anywhere.

Comment: i tried with this code from yesterday but receiving error ```

Comment: i tried with this code from yesterday but receiving error. i think there is problem with my code in line `output[i][j] = numbers1[i][j] + numbers2[i][j]` and in the `testAdditionOfArray` function. And i have one more question that, we need to give array matrix values in test code right? how you wrote `expected` and `actual` code in Junit code. Please clarify my doubt. @thinkgruen

Comment: we can write different test cases in singe Junit test case, am i correct? Can you please help me with different test cases like `single column matrix, single row matrix and 2x3 matrix` @thinkgruen

Comment: to the last question: you can add multiple assertions to a single test case, yes, but it is clearer if you write a single test case for a single method. I am not sure what you mean by "how you wrote expected and actual" - you can pretty much pick any matrix you like, so i chose a 2x2 identity matrix to test. `actual` is what is the output from your method using this 2x2 matrix, `expected` is the matrix multiplied by two (as this is how your addition works)

Comment: By adding these 2 commands `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;` `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;` throwing an error as "import org.junit.jupiter cannot be resolved". I run the code without these 2 commands but i used `import static org.junit.Assert.*;` `import org.junit.Test;` these 2 source files. eventhow the test case giving error, why it is happen please explain. Thank you

Comment: ah yes, since you didn't include the junit version, i assumed junit 5 is okay. so in this case you are still using junit 4

Comment: I added _Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library -> JUnit -> Junit 3/4_ There is no Junit5 version. how to solve this issue?

Comment: it's not an issue at all, you can use 4 as well

Comment: I edited my question please take a look and please tell me how to solve it. Thank you @thinkgruen

Comment: change the `i` in `for(int j=0; i< length2; j++)` with `for(int j=0; j<number[i].length; j++)` - you had an `i` in your loop, not a `j`. please ask follow-ups in a separate question as I feel your initial question was already adequately answered.

Comment: Yes you answered my question. Thank you for the last change which i made mistake. I am getting one last error in Junit test at `actual` line. Do you know why? i will close this question with this.

Comment: the only error in the test is that your `expected` matrix is wrong, should be `new int[][]{{11, 6},{11,6}}`

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example and read the comments to understand a little better, I really hope that this code works for you or at least give you an idea about how
matrix multiply works:

```
/* A naive recursive implementation that simply follows
the above optimal substructure property */
class MatrixChainMultiplication {
    // Matrix Ai has dimension p[i-1] x p[i] for i = 1..n
    static int MatrixChainOrder(int p[], int i, int j)
    {
        if (i == j)
            return 0;

        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        // place parenthesis at different places between
        // first and last matrix, recursively calculate
        // count of multiplications for each parenthesis
        // placement and return the minimum count
        for (int k = i; k < j; k++)
        {
            int count = MatrixChainOrder(p, i, k)
                        + MatrixChainOrder(p, k + 1, j)
                        + p[i - 1] * p[k] * p[j];

            if (count < min)
                min = count;
        }

        // Return minimum count
        return min;
    }

    // Driver code
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int arr[] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3 };
        int n = arr.length;

        System.out.println(
            "Minimum number of multiplications is "
            + MatrixChainOrder(arr, 1, n - 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, I wrote basic matrix multiplication code, which is same format the code above i wrote (`MatrixAdd`). But i want Junit test code. how to test Junit test of matrix addition and multiplication. If possible can you please help me with full code of main and Junit for add and mul. Thank you @ Alva Santi